# DocuSign REST API Explorer Request Signature Document Upload not working in FireFox or IE 9

Tags: rest, docusignapi

On the DocuSign website http://iodocs.docusign.com/ the REST API Explorer does not allow the user to upload a document in order to test the Request Signature From Document. Clicking on the "+" sign does not provide a way to upload a file and thus test the API. I have provided my Account Email and Password and Integrator Key. Other portions of the same page work, enabling me to enter Signers, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Try refreshing your browser cache / temp files.  I think I've seen this before and refreshing fixed it.

I just tested now and after entering my credentials and hitting the plus next to documents it opens a file browser window for me where I can select the document.

Comment: I cleared out everything and it still does not work. I opened Firebug and I could see that there was nothing triggered when I clicked on the "+" sign next to document but there was when I clicked on the other "+" signs. Not sure what's wrong.

Comment: Works fine for me when I use Chrome or Safari, have you tried with either of those browsers?

Comment: Sorry, but two of the most popular browsers should work, I'm not downloading another.

Comment: OK, I bit the bullet and downloaded Chrome and sure enough it works. However, the REST API Explorer still cannot delete a Recipient.

Comment: Well, I went back to see if I could try this again and could not find the Delete Recipient method in the REST API Explorer! And, the Delete Document was no longer working.

Comment: I can see it there right now, is the delete recipient method still not showing for you?  If so you might want to try clearing your browser cache...